# Degraded performance using python's 'threading' on a Nginx server comparing to a local machine

Tags: python, multithreading, nginx, flask, python-multithreading

I've built a Flask application, that computes some paths in a graph. Usually, it's a very greedy task and it takes a lot of time to finish calculations. While I was busy with configuring algorithm, I didn't really pay attention to the server side implementations. We've set up an Nginx server, that servers that whole thing. Here's main Flask route:

```
@app.route('/paths', methods=['POST'])
def paths():
    form = SampleForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        point_a = form.point_a.data
        point_b = form.point_b.data
        start = form.start.data.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        end = form.end.data.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        hops = form.hops.data

        rendering_time, collections = make_collection(point_a, point_b, start, end, hops)
        return render_template(
            'result.html',
            searching_time=rendering_time,
            collections=collections)

    else:
        logger.warning('Bad form: {}'.format(form.errors))
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

The whole calculation thing lies under `make_collection` method. So, whenever user sends request to the `server.com/path`, he will have to wait, until the method completes calculations and returns something. This is not a pleasing solution, sometimes Nginx just goes timeout.

The next version of this was with a simple idea of delegating labor work to some thread and just returning an empty page to the user. Later on we can just update page contents with the latest searhing results.

```
@app.route('/paths', methods=['POST'])
def paths():
    form = SampleForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        point_a = form.point_a.data
        point_b= form.point_b.data
        start = form.start.data.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        end = form.end.data.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        hops = form.hops.data

        finder = threading.Thread(
            target=make_collection,
            kwargs={
                'point_a': point_a,
                'point_b': point_b,
                'start': start,
                'end': end,
                'hops': hops})
        finder.start()

        rendering_time, collections = 0, []
        return render_template(
            'result.html',
            searching_time=rendering_time
            collections=collections)

    else:
        logger.warning('Bad form: {}'.format(form.errors))
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

The code above works fine and with accepatable searching time(didn't changed from the first version, like expected). The problem is, it works like that only on my local machine. When I deploy this to the Nginx, the total performance is not even nearly close to what I'm expecting. For comparison, results that I find on my local machine under 30 seconds, Nginx cannot fully find even under 300 seconds. What to do?

P.S. Originially, setting up Nginx server wasn't my part of the job and I'm not very familiar how Nginx works, but if you need any info, please, ask.

Comment: There are multiple possibilities. With the most obvious one: if `make_collection` is a cpu-bound task then the performance depends on total available cpu power on the machine (which means that all active processes/threads try to get their cpu time, reducing performance). And even if it isn't cpu bound it may still be slow because of the machine if for example you have everything on one machine (i.e. the app, database, nginx, etc). Have you checked that? You may also want to try to debug nginx, i.e. check if the delay is due to nginx (unlikely) or the app.

Comment: Also note that what you are doing is bad. Each request spawns a new thread. If I call `/paths` multiple times you will end up with hundreds or thousands background threads. This kills performance as well. You need some queue and a thread pool instead. Just to control the amount of spawned tasks. BTW What server do you use for Flask? Uwsgi? Gunicorn? Raw Flask (unrecommended)? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

First code snippet looks like an easy way to let client fetch calculations results.

However, `make_collection` is a blocking one and Nginx will keep one of its workers busy with it. Since usual way of Nginx configuration is to have one worker per CPU core, that leaves you with one worker less each time you make a HTTP request to `/paths`. If there are multiple requests to `/paths` then is not surprise that you get a poor performance. Not to mention WSGI server that you probably have e.g. uwsgi, gunicorn, etc. and their workers and threads per worker process.

Solution with threads might look like a good solution, but you can end up with a lot of threads. Pay attention to threads in Python and try to avoid CPU bound work from being delegated to threads in Python unless you really know what you are doing.

In general you should try to avoid these blocking calls, like the one you make and offload them to a separate worker queue while keeping a reference for getting results later on.